# when to apply cauchy's-lemma 1 or cauchy's-lemma 2 or jordan's-lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I know the procedure of computing contour integration of a given complex function using cauchy's lemma's rule.But,I am confused about when to use cauchy's-lemma 1 and when caushy's-lemma 2 or jordan's-lemma. Please help me understanding that.please be as simple as you can.

**My Assumption:** If the poles stay in the region of the semicircle but outside the real axis(means ,if the singular points are imaginary) ,then we have to use lemma 2 (big semicircle). But,if the pole stays on real axis ,then I have to use Lemma 1.Is it right?

Comment: You can also always use "Lemma 1", but change the reference: first look for the result you need, then look for a book that calls it *Lemma 1*.

Comment: would you please be a little bit descriptive ?

Comment: For instance, let's say I am not even doing complex analysis and I want to use Heine-Cantor's theorem, but I don't want to write German names. I can write something like "*By* **Lemma 1**, *continuous functions on a compact set are uniformly continuous*", provided I've made clear that I am referencing a textbook that actually calls Heine-Cantor's theorem "Lemma 1".

Comment: it is cauchy's lemma.